# not showing data in dom reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Hello everyone I am beginner at react. I want to search i my state which array of object I write the following function for the search. It works perfectly fine in Console.log();
But not working in real dom thanks in advance

```
categorySearch(event){

    const filteredElements = 
       this.state.data.filter(categoryObject => categoryObject.name.includes(event.target.value));
    this.setState({filteredElements: filteredElements}); 
    console.log(filteredElements); 
}
```

here is code for list

```
this.state.data.map((item,index) => {

        return (
          <div key={index} id="area">
            <h3>{item.name}</h3>
            <div id="overflowTest"><List lists={item.lists} handle={this.handleItemClicked} /> </div>
          </div>
        )
      }
```

Comment: Not working means ? It's not print the data or any other error ?

Comment: Can you please print the JSON what's there in this.state.data ?

Comment: Sir there is no errors.
But working in dom and everything is perfectly fine in consle

Comment: @HarshMakadia Sir this.state.data is array of Object's

Comment: Added a sample below to show you have to render an array of object.Please check it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say this is your JSON

```js
[
 {name: "John", id: 120, age: 22, gender: "male"},
 {name: "Beth", id: 443, age: 24, gender: "female"},
 {name: "Jane", id: 510, age: 19, gender: "female"}
]
```

And now if you want to render this you have to write as shown below

```js
render() {
 return(
   <ul>
     {this.state.users.map(function(user, i){
       return <li key={i}>{user.name}</li>
     )}
   </ul>
 )
}
```

This is a simple example of rendering the JSON. Since I've no idea about your state data I have taken a sample array to show you how the rendering works.
I hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Sir that's what i done but now i want to search in the about JSON can you please guide for that Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use a filter to search in the JSON for more details on how the filter works - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter